# Using ^ but not as a power symbol in latex

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters

I want to write `a^b` in latex where `^` is not a power symbol. If I just write `b^a` in latex, the latter obliged me to put `$`. But in fact I don't want to write `a` to the power `b`, but just `a^b`.

How can I solve this issue?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you not use \^ ?

Comment: In what context would you use `a^b`?

Comment: @Plergux `\^` is the accent, `\textasciicircum` is `^`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, ok. Sorry :|

Comment: @Plergux \^ doesn't work. It is really the accent as DavidCarlisle mentioned.

Comment: @egreg I am writing a matlab code in latex. In matlab, the power is given by the symbol ^

Comment: But if you're writing code (especially if it's a lot), you might want to look into the packages `listings` or `minted`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, `\string` can be used to avoid special (catcode induced) interpretations of the token than follows.

Such syntax will work in both text as well as math modes, though, of course, `a` and `b` will be rendered in the math font, in such a case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a\string^b $a\string^b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works well.

Answer (score 3):

This is `\textasciicircum` in text mode, and can be used in math mode as well with proper wrappers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mathcaret{\mathbin{\textup{\textasciicircum}}}

\begin{document}
a {\textasciicircum} b

\(a \mathcaret  b \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer modern font sample]

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions also work very well.